# clang: finding the SourceRange/SourceLocation of a QualType

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree

While iterating the AST I encounter VarDecl objects. These have a type, "QualType".
Now I would like to find the location in the original source of these QualTypes.
I've heard somewhere that TypeLocBuilder can be used for this but whatever I try it always throws an assert like `T == LastTy && "type doesn't match last type pushed!"'.
So the question is: how can I use TypeLocBuilder for this? And if it is not useful for this, what alternative is there?

```
TypeLoc buildTypeLoc(ASTContext *const c, const QualType qt)
{
       TypeLocBuilder tlb;
       return tlb.getTypeLocInContext(*c, qt);
}

SourceRange getQualTypeSourceRange(ASTContext *const c, const QualType qt)
{
      return buildTypeLoc(c, qt).getSourceRange();
}

for(clang::ASTUnit::top_level_iterator dit = au -> top_level_begin(); dit != au -> top_level_end(); dit++) {
        if (isa<VarDecl>(*dit)) {
                const VarDecl *vd = static_cast<const VarDecl *>(*dit);

                SourceRange sr = getQualTypeSourceRange(&au -> getASTContext(), vd -> getType());
        }
}
```